# Jagged edges SkyBox realtime

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm Completely new at setting up lights, 
I have tried to adjust settings following several tutorials
 but fail to find how to correct jagged objects have non crisp look

- 1 Unity unit = 1 meter (100cm)
- Linear rendering mode is used Deferred
- HDR is enabled for camera
- Deferred rendering mode is used
- Post Process package is installed
- Enable Color Grading > Tonemapper > ACES

Help appreciated!

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I altered the scene to add light probes + reflection probes,
Set static objects. Its seems to be better, although it would be nice to find how to speed up baking times... happier with the result though

In the light mapping settings I set 
Direct Denoiser to OpenImageDenoise
Indirect Denoiser to OpenImageDenoise

[image]
[image]